# Can I include a file based on a variable

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to include a template file dynamically, but the variable does not appear to expand in the include declaration. How is this best done?

```
{% for file in files %}
  {% include "{{ file }}.txt" %}
{% endfor %}
```

The error I am getting is:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: {{ file }}.txt

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me.

I would like to clarify having a `"."` in jinja2 might create an issue so it would be better to pass the entire filename with extension to jinja2.

The usage of double quotes would not render the variable value so it would remain as it is like `{{ file }}`

**The below works:**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

data = '''
{% for file in files.split(",") %}
  {% include file %}
{% endfor %}
'''

template = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("templates/")).from_string(data)

msg = template.render(files="1.txt")

print(msg)
```

**Output:**

```
 1.txt
```